# can we post the getelement.id('').innerhtml from submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i want to get value from .innerhtml to post it with submit form, but it not work. different from the post value of the query it work well. this code i tried.

```
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method="post" 
style="width:auto;" >
//i want post 3452 to other file2
<div class="box">
<span class='odometer' id="timespan">3452</span>
</div>

<input class="process"  name="submit" type="submit" value="Pemenang" 
onclick="location.href='file2.php?RWD_IMG=<?php echo 
$rwdimg?>&RWD_DET_NBR=<?php echo $rwdetz?>&RWD_HEADS_NBR=<?php echo 
$RwdNbr?>&RWD_DESC=<?php echo $DESC;?>&TOTALREWARD=<?php echo 
$totalreward;? 
>&POIN='+document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function which handles that location change:

```
<script>
  function changeLocation() {
    return location.href = <?php echo $rwdimg ?>&RWD_DET_NBR=<?php echo $rwdetz ?>&RWD_HEADS_NBR=<?php echo $RwdNbr ?>&RWD_DESC=<?php echo $DESC; ?>&TOTALREWARD=<?php echo $totalreward; ?> + document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML
  }
</script>
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" method="post" style="width:auto;" >
  <div class="box">
  <span class='odometer' id="timespan">3452</span>
</div>
<input class="process"  name="submit" type="submit" value="Pemenang" onclick="changeLocation" />
</form>
```

Comment: i still can't get the value of .innerhtml

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor is it `undefined`?